# how to delete mysql table row from mail inbox

Tags: php, mysql, email, inbox

I want to delete mysql table row from mail inbox , Is it possible !, If yes how can i delete the table row in my server database from any mail inbox account, please tell me the solution

Table Structure:

```
id  usrname  password  status usercat
1   xxxxxxx  xxxxxxx   new    1
2   uuuuuuu  uuuuuuu   new    5

$del_qry= mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE some_column=some_value")
```

In my site after Registration, the registered person get alert mail and also site admin get registered user detail's mail. So if the admin  want to delete the second user(username - uuuuuu) from his mail account.

How can i do this, Please tell me i am new here...

Comment: You need to provide more information. Table structures, example queries you have tried and other details can help us help you with the problem. This question will remain unanswered unless you provide more information.

Comment: Please read the FAQ on how to ask questions. We need more info :)

Comment: just normal delete mysql query like this 'DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE some_column=some_value'. but i want to run this query from my email inbox. i am new here, plz help me!!!

Comment: " i want to run this query from my email inbox" What does that mean?

Comment: @user1379083 do you mean, you want to add a link to an email that will remove a row from your table when clicked?

Comment: yes jack that's one i want !!!!

Answer (score 2):

The email you send to the admin will have to contain a link like this:

```
http://www.example.org/admin/remove_account.php?id=123
```

Where `123` is the user that was registered and `remove_account.php` is the script that will be loaded when the link is clicked.

Within the script you would have something like this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
```

**CAUTION**

A few words of caution. The above link should be protected by one of the following:

- User & password protection (either using Apache or PHP)
- Signature protection (example below)

The signature protection prevents tampering / forging link parameters by adding a signature. Works like this:

```
$secret = "some reasonably long string of random data";
$id = "123"; // like above, the user id

$sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $id, $secret);

$link = 'http://www.example.org/admin/remove_account.php?' . http_build_query(array(
    'id' => $id,
    'sig' => $sig,
));
```

To verify the signature:

```
$secret = "some reasonably long string of random data";
if (isset($_GET['id'], $_GET['sig'])) {
    $calc_sig = hash_hmac('sha1', $_GET['id'], $secret);
    if ($calc_sig === $_GET['sig']) {
        // your delete query here
    }
}
```

Please note that, although the link protects against someone trying to access your administrative script, if it falls in the wrong hands you're still pretty much screwed. Don't underestimate security :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add a link of a page of your site in email of delete with respect of user list. and when user click on link it will redirect to particular page where it will get that user id from url of link and then you can perform delete action. It is necessary to redirect to site page from mail because in mail you can not direct connect with database.

thanks